# HTTP 500 error launcing ASP.NET 3.0 application

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8, asp.net-core-3.0

I have just upgraded our **ASP.NET Core** 2.2 web application to 3.0. It builds and deploys fine. The problem is when I go to run it from our **IIS** server. This was running perfectly fine as a *Core 2.2* web app, but now fails since upgrading to *Core 3.0*.

When I launch the web app from the commandline there are no reported errors.

[image]

When I launch the application from the browser the Windows logs indicate that the app started correctly.

[image]

The app then fails with an **HTTP 500** error. Here are the **IIS** log entries.

[image]

We're using *Windows Server 2012 R2* with *IIS 8.5.9600.16384*

The app appears to start correctly but then fails with an **HTTP 500** error. Has anyone else seen this or something similar? Any ideas how to diagnose / fix the problem?

**UPDATE**

I've attached the VS 2019 debugger to the deployed app via the w3wp.exe process and it's not even hitting any of the middleware (I have a breakpoint at Startup() in Startup.cs).

I've tried changing the application pool settings e.g. identity, .NET version but to no avail.

When I launch the site from the web server I get the following error message which doesn't really tell me anything.

[image]

I can't see what's causing the problem.

Comment: Try to debug from the main method line by line and try to figure out which line is reponsible for throwing the 500 error.

Comment: How would I debug a deployed web app?

Comment: you can attach the corresponding w3wp.exe (iis worker process) that should be attaching your DLL if it is deployed as inprocess. If, for some reason, it is outofproc, then you should have yourproject.exe running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation and comparison of the build artifacts that the build produces vs the deployed app, I discovered that the **appsettings.json** was not being deployed. No idea how or when this started failing, but it caused the app to generate an **HTTP 500** error message. Our app's **Azure ADB2C** settings are contained in this file so it was crashing trying to authenticate but couldn't find the authentication settings.

There was no obvious error being generated and everything seemed to be loading fine. It was at the point at which the app was trying to authenticate that it was failing. All working now.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 3.0 uses the in-process hosting model by default. You may need to upgrade the [.NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle).

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.0 with the .NET Core 3.0 Hosting Bundle. As far as I can tell everything is configured correctly.

Comment: What happens if you hit the site in a web browser running on the server itself? You should get a more detailed error message.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I'm running the site on the server but getting no detailed error message at all. It's like it isn't even hitting any of the code. I can't tell if it's an IIS issue or some other mis-configuration somewhere.

Comment: When you hit your site, what _do_ you get back in the browser? A completely blank page?

Comment: I've updated my question - see above for a scdreenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You will check web.config "aspNetCore"

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

maybe proccessPath is wrong.

if it doesn't solve  problem , write to log step step startup.cs. 
Maybe throw error in startup.cs